# Cannot initialize AndroidDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, android-emulator, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

At W2k8 64 bit I have in the android emulator instance of android 4.1  API Level 16 with ARM as CPU.
After launch of it I'm running my UnitTest and on the first line

```
 var webDriver = new AndroidDriver("http://localhost:8080/wd/hub"); //also with no argument
```

I got an exception:

```
Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

Version of this WebDriver is 2.25.1.0.

I followed this article:

http://www.nishantverma.com/2011/06/installing-webdriver-on-android.html

When I'm using other drivers like Firefox- or ChromeDriver works fine.

I would be gratefull for any advice

Answer (score 1):

I might be telling you what you already know, but have you started the tcp port forwarding to android server you are running. for reference check **[Android Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Install_the_APK)**

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done it now according to the instruction from http://www.nishantverma.com/2011/06/installing-webdriver-on-android.html but I cannot connect(404) to the  http://localhost:8080/wd/hub. Also there is no communicate "jetty started". And of course error in code is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not starting for some reason. Is it possible you already have something else running on port 8080?

Try running `netstat -a -n` and see if port 8080 is listed.

If it is in use, you might try setting up on a different port or killing the process which is using that port.

You might also try disabling UAC and Firewall on your machine and/or running the process as Administrator and see if that helps (This would be temporary of course, don't leave these off).